# How can I update pear in XAMPP? deprecated code in pear

Tags: php, xampp, pear

Using XAMPP I am trying to install a pear extension (phpuml) but all I got were errors:

```
Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported
```

It appeared to me, that my efforts were fruitless because the pear code was not up to date. I changed every line of code containing the old syntax with the curly braces to the new brackets. After some iterations of trial and error I got some sugar. It was a new error:

```
Too few arguments to function error_handler(), 4 passed and exactly 5 expected (...more blah)
```

Now I am not the guy to try and fix some mayor issue in someone elses code because I am simply either too dumb or not knowledgable enough to fix such a huge project.

So I was trying to update pear but with this last error I couldn't even use some updating function. What can I do now? And isn't it bad that XAMPP comes with a deprecated version of pear installed?

Comment: oh yea btw. Fruitpuns intended and will be appreciated.

Comment: which pear version, which php version and which phpuml version do you have?

Comment: @cweiske PHP 8.1.6, can't check pear right now but i guess "old". The same version that xampp has included in its 8.1.6 installation. phpuml is not installed.